# Python Non-Loop Way to change array values based on row and column position

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am trying to change numpy-array values based on their column and row location and currently am achieving it this way:

```
for r in range(ResultArr2.shape[0]):
    for c in range(ResultArr2.shape[1]):
        ResultArr2[r,c] = ResultArr2[r,c]-r*1000-c*500
```

Is there a non-loop way of achieving the same result? I know that Python often works faster if one implements non-loop structure, but I could not find out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few variants using either `mgrid` or `ogrid` or manually creating the same ranges that `ogrid` generates.

Observations:

- for an array of size  1000, the fastest method is more than three times faster than `mgrid`
- using `ogrid` or manual it is a bit better to add the two ranges separately, thereby avoiding a full size temporary
- conveniences such as `mgrid` or `ogrid` tend to come at a cost in `numpy`, and indeed the manual method is twice as fast as `ogrid`

Code:

```
import numpy as np

from timeit import timeit

A = np.arange(1000).reshape(20, 50)

def f():
    B = A.copy()
    m, n = B.shape
    I, J = np.mgrid[:m*1000:1000, :n*500:500]
    B += I+J
    return B

def g():
    B = A.copy()
    m, n = B.shape
    I, J = np.ogrid[:m*1000:1000, :n*500:500]
    B += I+J
    return B

def h():
    B = A.copy()
    m, n = B.shape
    I, J = np.ogrid[:m*1000:1000, :n*500:500]
    B += I
    B += J
    return B

def i():
    B = A.copy()
    m, n = B.shape
    BT = B.T
    BT += np.arange(0, 1000*m, 1000)
    B += np.arange(0, 500*n, 500)
    return B

def j():
    B = A.copy()
    m, n = B.shape
    B += np.arange(0, 1000*m, 1000)[:, None]
    B += np.arange(0, 500*n, 500)
    return B


assert np.all(f()==h())
assert np.all(g()==h())
assert np.all(i()==h())
assert np.all(j()==h())

print(timeit(f, number=10000))
print(timeit(g, number=10000))
print(timeit(h, number=10000))
print(timeit(i, number=10000))
print(timeit(j, number=10000))
```

Sample run:

```
0.289166528998976    # mgrid                                                                                               
0.25259370900130307  # ogrid 1 step                                                                                               
0.24528862700026366  # ogrid 2 steps                                                                                               
0.09056068700010655  # manual transpose                                                                                             
0.08238107499892067  # manual add dim
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
arr = np.random.uniform(size=(5,5))

n_rows, n_cols = arr.shape
r, c = np.ogrid[0:n_rows, 0:n_cols]
arr -= 1000 * r + 500 * c
```

Comment: That is great - exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Better use `ogrid`. The exact equivalent is `arr -= 1000 * r + 500 * c`.